# Refresh summary buffer in gnus

Tags: emacs, gnus

When I'm reading messages in `gnus` I would like to have new messages show up dynamically in my `*Summary*` buffer as they arrive. Currently I have to go back to the `*Group*` buffer and then select `INBOX` again... Is there a way to refresh the `*Summary*` buffer without going back to `*Group*`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `/ N`, in the Summary buffer, that is, `gnus-summary-insert-new-articles`.

Comment: That will not make the deleted articles go away.

Comment: @EnzoChi I believe `x` will do what you want.

Comment: @mgalgs That bound to `gnus-summary-limit-to-unread`, not what I expect. I want the deleted articles go away which is the same as quit to `*Group*` and then enter `Summary` again.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is `M-g` I think. It will get ride of the deleted articles. This shortcut is bound to `gnus-summary-rescan-group`.

Basically it will exit the group, ask for new articles then select the group again.